# What is the safest way to recognize if a file is application/pkcs7-mime or analogous in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, browser, file-type, pkcs

I need to know a safe method to detect application/pkcs7-mime or similar files. One way would be to detect the final extension of the file but I would like to know if there is something better than that.
In reading it is possible to detect the '**type**' attribute of the file but this will not be compiled on all browsers for this type of extension, such as eg. on firefox.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To recognize if a file is application/pkcs7-mime or analogous in Angular, you can use the MIME type of the file.
In iOS 8, the file must have the MIME type application/pkcs7-mime and it must be CMS signed by a valid TLS certificate.
You can get the MIME type from filename extension using C#.
If you are using Ionic Apps, you can handle custom URL schemes and host domains in your install command.

To configure S/MIME for Windows, open the Mail app and select a certificate.